# Bottom fixed child div inside in another child div

Tags: html, css

I have  a small problem. I have two columns filled with dynamic text. Both are the same height according to bigger one. Now, I want another fixed div after the content of the bigger div. My html code is:

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.child1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #c5e997;
  width: 49%;
  position: relative;
}

.child2 {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="child1">
    Random text here Less dynamic text
    <div class="child2">
      Fixed
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="child1">
    Random text here<br/> More
    <br/> Dynamic
    <br/> Text
    <br/> Here
    <div class="child2">
      Fixed
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

So, any idea how to set the second div after the higher dynamic text?
In this moment, the "Fixed" text is displayed over the longest text.

L.E.: you can see the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/fte087p7/
Thank you!

Comment: Absolutely positioned element is at the bottom of its parent with `position: relative`. It's okay, where is the problem? Learn how position relative/absolute work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.child1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #c5e997;
  width: 49%;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.child2 {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="child1">
    Random text here Less dynamic text
    <div class="child2">
      Text
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="child1">
    Random text here
    <br/> More
    <br/> Dynamic
    <br/> Text
    <br/> Here
    <div class="child2">
      Fixed
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

How about adding `padding-bottom` in `.child1`?